# Duplicate results when i am searching tags on SO

Tags: support, stack-overflow, search, tag-search

I have tried to search 2 tags(PostgreSQL, Mysql) on Stackover Flow. But search results are showing every question 2 times like below image.

Whether its a bug? It should not behave like this.

[image]

Comment: That's not duplicates: note the difference of the first letter in the title of each result. A vs Q.

Comment: Ya, i have rushed in asking question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be clear it's not showing the questions twice - it's actually showing you the question and then the answers to the question (if there are any). Search returns both questions and answers.

If you want to only include questions in your results, then you can include a filter of `is:question`.  You can see the Advanced Search options by clicking `Advanced Search Tips`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You're getting results for all posts, not only questions. The first post in your search results is of an answer, that's what the "A:" prefix means. The second result is a question, indicated by the "Q:".

If you would like questions only, then add `is:q` to your search and you will not see answers.

Answer (score 2):

One is answer and other one is question. If you want to filter further, you can use `is:q` or `is:a` in the search bar.

Related help center article: [How do I search?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching)

Answer (score 1):

All current answers here missed the simple and honest mistake made: using a comma.

In order to show questions having two tags, just [have a space between them, no comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+mysql):

[image: tag search with no comma]

This way you'll get only the questions, no answers, in the search results.

By adding a comma (or anything else) you turn this into ordinary search, which returns both questions and answers, as covered by other answers here.