# When are multiple closure reasons provided in the post notice?

Tags: support, closed-questions, close-reasons, post-notices

I noticed in [this recently closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351214/622284) that there are multiple close reasons presented.

Here's a screenshot of the post notice:

[image: Post notice with multiple community-specific closure reasons chosen]

From my understanding, only one close reason is selected when closure occurs, and this reason is typically the reason chosen first, most highly-voted for, or the reason a moderator chose.

Quoting [this previously proposed duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339401/622284):

> Multiple canned off-topic reasons are no longer shown on closures going forward; instead, only one is shown, and the one that gets shown is the first one to have been voted for. (This does not affect questions closed prior to the revamp.)

But this doesn't appear to be true given that multiple closure reasons are visible above.

Question closure was very recently updated to no longer show the users who voted to close to the author in the author's post notice. Instead, it simply explains the closure reason and gives guidance on what to do next.

So... When are multiple closure reasons displayed?

Further, is this intentional? When the post notice changes were launched, it appeared that only the highest (or first) voted off-topic/community-specifc reason was chosen. Is this no longer the case?

Comment: This used to happen on a split vote, say, 3-2, with the names behind them. Suspect it's still something along those lines.

Comment: For what it's worth, that is [no-repro because the OP withdrew the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351214/duplicate-results-when-i-am-searching-tags-on-so#comment1176187_351214). Every site's search works that way, so it's not applicable to one site. --- Without both reasons there might only be the incorrect one, which I suspect would be frustrating.

Comment: @Glorfindel the dupe target says this is only supposed to happen for questions closed prior to November '19, while the question Spevacus linked to was closed 22 hours ago... Do you think it may make this worth reopening (being a bug/reversal of the behavior from November 19?)

Comment: Yeah, might be a bug then (or an inaccuracy in the answer, but that's less likely given who its author is). My apologies for using the dupehammer too early.

Comment: @Glorfindel I, too, am unwilling to suspect that author being wrong, but it seems something has changed recently :)

Comment: I don't recall which question it was now, but I also saw a close dialog with multiple reasons given, where I was one of the vote closers on a split vote, just a few days ago on Math SE.

Comment: @JohnOmielan If you could find it and provide a screenshot (the expanded info is only available to >3k users) that'd be helpful. I think it only applies to *recently* closed questions that have a split community-specific-reason vote.

Comment: @Spevacus I could imagine that the pattern follows something like _2-1-2_ close voters with distinct reasons.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Nope, my answer that was quoted from was incorrect the whole time. I've removed the incorrect bullet.

Comment: To provide a fuller explanation: the update was added shortly after the new close reasons were implemented. At the time, the team was experimenting with different things (e.g. showing old "not constructive" and "not a real question" close reasons as newer ones), and the bullet in my answer was correct. However, the team later reverted those experiments, which means that bullet is incorrect now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two reasons are shown in the close notice if two voters (or a moderator) chose one community-specific canned reason, and 2-3 other voters chose a different one.

The behavior hasn't changed from the [implementation prior to the rollout of the new notices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/339401/5), with the exception that the specific users who voted for specific canned reasons aren't shown anymore.

The extra bullet in my answer you linked comes from the fact that it was edited *just* after the new reasons were rolled out: at that time, the team was experimenting with different behaviors of the close reason choice procedure, such as showing older "not constructive" and "not a real question" closures as newer reasons, as well as only showing one canned reason at a time even though multiple were voted for. All of those experiments were later reverted, which left that bullet you cite inaccurate.

Comment: You're irreplaceable. :) Cheers, Sonic.

Answer (score 4):

The Math SE [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3764076/602049), which was closed 3 days ago, has this expanded close reasons dialog

[image: Expanded close reasons dialog with multiple reasons provided]

and here is one from the deleted Math SE [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3763401/602049) posted 4 days ago

[image: Second expanded close reasons dialog with multiple reasons provided]

I recall seeing multiple close reasons given at least several more times over the past few months, but I don't remember for which posts or when they occurred. Since I've voted to close a lot of questions over that period, I'm not going to search for them now.  However, I believe they were all similar to what is shown above and in the OP's post itself, i.e., as [Spevacus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/622284/spevacus)'s question [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351259/when-are-multiple-closure-reasons-provided-in-the-post-notice?noredirect=1#comment1176395_351259) suggests, this occurs when there's a split community-specific reason vote.

Comment: Earlier the post notices (when they were yellow-ish) used to show who voted for that communtiy specific close reason.